# Pandas create a conditional column based on cumulative logic operations of the other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns that represent the on switch and off switch indicator. I want to create a column called last switch where it keeps record the 'last' direction of the switch (whether it is on or off). Another condition is that if both on and off switch value is 1 for a particular row, then the 'last switch' output will return the opposite sign of the previous last switch. Currently I managed to find a solution to get this almost correct except facing the situation where both on and off shows 1 that makes my code wrong.

I also attached the screenshot with a desired output. Please help appreciate all.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,1],[0,1]], columns=['on','off'])

df['last_switch']=(df['on']-df['off']).replace(0,method='ffill')
```

[image]

Comment: isn't at index position 11 the value of desired output is `-1`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas It should be 1 because at pos 9, last switch was 1, and by pos 10 because both indicator has 1, so the desired last switch should do opposite and back to -1. Following the same logic, at pos 11, boht indicator has 1 again, so we do another opposite switch and switch it back to 1.

Comment: @manwong0606, how are you calculating values `0` & `1` equals `-1`  and `1 & 1` equals `-1`  while `1 & 0` equals `1` in desired cols ?

Comment: @KarnKumar last switch output should depends on the last 'switch' whose value equals to 1. e.g. in pos 2, off is 1 and on is 0, so the last switch is -1. between pos 2 and pos 6 there is NO new on/off value , so the last switch stays the same at -1. In pos 6 'on' becomes 1, so the last switch switched back from -1 to 1.

Comment: Ideally, by pos 7, both on and off value is 1 (activated), and because the last switch (i.e. at pos 6 is 1), so the desired output is to 'switch it', i.e. to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your existing code:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df['prev']=df['last_switch'].shift()
    df.loc[(df['on']==1) & (df['off']==1), 'last_switch']=df['prev'] * (-1)
df.drop('prev', axis=1, inplace=True)
df['last_switch']=df['last_switch'].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    on  off  last_switch
0    1    0            1
1    1    0            1
2    0    1           -1
3    0    1           -1
4    0    0           -1
5    0    0           -1
6    1    0            1
7    1    1           -1
8    0    1           -1
9    1    0            1
10   1    1           -1
11   1    1            1
12   0    1           -1
```

Let me know if you need expanation of the code

Comment: Thank you and they are well understood. I thought about using loop but I want to avoid them and aim to do it in a more pandas manner (operate in a scalar fashion, but not using looping)

Comment: Also, this loop can be an issue if my df has 100,000+ rows which makes it quite slow

Comment: I understand. The problem is that you need some kind of loop through the last_switch column, as values change dynamically. 
I tried some similar solution with numpy (np.roll) but it doesn't update dynamically either.
In this case I would prefer a common loop. 
Even the df.apply solution will work with a loop in the background

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[0,0],[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,1],[0,1]], columns=['on','off'])
df['last_switch']=(df['on']-df['off']).replace(0,method='ffill')

prev_row = None
def apply_logic(row):
    global prev_row
    if prev_row is not None:
        if (row["on"] == 1) and (row["off"] == 1):
            row["last_switch"] = -prev_row["last_switch"]
    prev_row = row.copy()
    return row
df.apply(apply_logic,axis=1)
```

personally i am not a big fan of using loop against dataframe. `shift` wont work in this case as the "last_switch" column is dynamic and subject to change based on on&off status.
Using your intermediate reesult with `apply` while carrying the value from previous row should do the trick. Hope it makes sense.